# Adding an element to XML with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am attempting to add an element to some XML using ElementTree.

```
<device>
    <general>
        <item1>text</item1>
    </general>
</device>
```

I want to add `<item2>text</item2>` under general.

I tried

```
ElementTree.SubElement(xml, '/device/general/item2')
ElementTree.SubElement(xml, 'general/item2')
```

to add the field in but both added new lines at the end of the XML rather than adding inside the existing general element.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you allowed to use beautiful soup?

Comment: No. I'm inside another Python module and only ElementTree is available to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `SubElement` must be the name of a single element; it cannot be a "path" like `general/item2`. Get a reference to the `general` element and add a subelement to it.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("device.xml")

general = tree.find(".//general")
item2 = ET.SubElement(general, "item2")
item2.text = "text"
```